# How to connect to MySQL created with docker to another port (not port 3306)?

Tags: mysql, docker

I already have installed mySql on my pc so port 3306 is already busy. This is the reason why I have to use a different port from 3306. I want to be able to connect with my machine to my docekr instance without using docker commands so I will be able to connect to that instance with my application (Spring web app).

Docker commands that I used:

```
docker run --name jt-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3307:3307 -d mysql
```

Then I tried to connect to that istance with:

```
mysql --user=root -P 3307 -p
```

In this case I get the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Please note that if I tried to use the instance installed on my pc it works, using with:

```
mysql --user=root -P 3306 -p
```

Other information about my docker instance using:

```
docker ps
```

I get:

> f52a94aa63da        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4
>   minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp,
>   0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp   jt-mysql

with status insided my docker image (entering using docker commands) I get:

```
Connection id:      11
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Binary data as:     Hexadecimal
Uptime:         16 min 50 sec
```

using env command:

```
HOSTNAME=f52a94aa63da
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
PWD=/
HOME=/root
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
GOSU_VERSION=1.7
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.19-1debian9
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command to start MySQL container at port 3306 and expose at port 3307

```
docker container run -d --name=LocalMySQLDB -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

OR

```
docker run -d --name=LocalMySQLDB -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

The above command with start the MySQL database server inside "LocalMySQLDB" container

Now to connect to the containerized mysql instance use below attached command

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -P 3307 -ppassword
```

I have tried this many a times on my local machine for testing purposes. It will definitely work for you as well.
Please comment if it will not work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Start Docker container using following command:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 --name mysql_server -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 mysql
```

Connect to container from host using following command:

```
mysql -u root -P 3307 --protocol=tcp -p
```

Comment: I get this error in this way: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Answer (score 1):

When you run docker container, please try to add this param at the end.

```
docker run --name jt-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3307:3306 -d mysql --network host
```

Comment: Don't you mean `-p 3307:3307` I think your command will expose container port 3307 to preoccupied 3306.

Comment: the port of mysql inside docker is 3306. so it expose 3306 port of docker container to your local 3307 port

Comment: @RobertB. in this way the container run for only few seconds and then stop. When I do docker start jt-mysql it is the same.